# how to edit past minDate in bootstrap3 date picker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap3 date picker, and using property minDate with today's date, now i need to change this date later, but i am unable to view yesterday's date in datepicker in edit mode, how to edit past minDate ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#datePickerID').prop('minDate' , [NEW DATE HERE]);
```

This should work I believe.